# Unable to create a mock object with mocha

Tags: ruby, ruby-mocha

I keep getting this error...

```
mockresponse.rb:4:in `createResponseObject': undefined method `mock' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Here's my code (a code example I swiped):

```
require 'mocha'

def createResponseObject
 @http_mock = mock('Net::HTTPResponse')
 @http_mock .stubs(:code => '200', :message => "OK", :content_type => "text/html", :body => '<title>Test</title><body>Body of the page</body>')
end

createResponseObject()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same issue as well.

I found the answer was to have 'gem mocha, :require => false' in my Gemfile.

My question: [NoMethodError: undefined method `mock' with Mocha and Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7609292/60131)